# How can download historical version of curl in zip file format with shell command?

Tags: git, version, repo

Get the latest version with `git clone`:

```
git clone  https://github.com/curl/curl.git
```

Check the version:

```
cd  curl
git log  #list the first 3 lines
commit def99e011e88d61a4157863537378ca9c59a79e0 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Stefan Eissing <stefan@eissing.org>
Date:   Mon Jun 26 11:51:43 2023 +0200   

git describe  def99e011e88d61a4157863537378ca9c59a79e0
curl-8_1_2-143-gdef99e011
```

We see that the version is `curl-8_1_2-143`.
Download the version `8_1_1` with browser:

```
https://github.com/curl/curl/releases
```

Click on `curl-8.1.1.zip` and save,i got the historical version of `curl-8_1_1` in zip file.

[image]

How can download historical version of curl in zip file format with shell command then?
The following shell command is not the way i wanted:

```
url="https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/569041/b283ef2d-8e6a-478c-97c1-00ccc68a0173?X-Amz-Algorithm=\
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20230709%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230709T054141Z&X-Amz-Expires=\
300&X-Amz-Signature=18425539998f0f6c17ac2f2a38a1e56573a7217f8bb87bf568549c43d5011a60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=512610&key_id=0&\
repo_id=569041&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dcurl-8.1.1.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream"
wget  $url -O curl.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did the clone, check out any version you want. `git checkout curl-8_1_1`

Or if you really really want the .zip, `git archive curl-8_1_1 -o curl-8_1_1.zip`

Comment: All change on version are recorded ,any version can extract from it, amazing!